# Is it possible to call a method pointer with a void* pointer to the object

Tags: c++

I have a struct, that contains a void* pointer to an object and a function pointer to some method of that object's class. I don't (and can't) have information of that objects' class, so I need a void*. I tried to call the method by this:

```
object->*function(args)
```

When I try to compile this with msvc I get two errors: C2296 and C2297
C2296 states, that the "->*" is invalid because the left operand is invalid because it is of type "void*"
C2297 states the same, but with the right operand and type "bool"

Comment: somehow " I don't (and can't) have information of that objects' class," doesnt fit together with having a member function pointer. If you have a member function pointer you need to know what is the type of the object

Comment: in other words: where is `function` coming from? If you want you can infer the type from the member function pointer, but as pointed out in the answer, that has to fit the actual type of the object

Comment: You can't have a pointer-to-member without knowing the type of the class it belongs to and its definition, so you either don't have such a pointer or you can (and do) have information about the class.

Comment: Show us the class instead of describing it in English.

Comment: I think you could use virtual functions as a simple alternative to what you're doing. I can't be certain unless you provide more information.

Comment: Ok, so some more information: what I am trying out is an event system that holds a vector of function pointers, that it calls, whenever an event occurs. This worked perfectly fine for simple functions. But member functions need an object. And I may be wrong, but I think the only difference to a normal function is, that it takes a hidden parameter, the pointer to the object. And, because pointers can be casted from void* to the class and vice versa I was assuming, that there would be some way (without using assembly), to call a member function using only two pointers.

Comment: I'll upload code later when I'm on pc again

Comment: maybe better open a new question. The one here looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but has an answer already, while the solution to your actual problem might be something else entirely. For example I'd start with questioning the use of `void*`. C++ has lots of facilities that make use of bare `void*` almost completely unnecessary (`std::any`, `std::variant` and relatives).

Comment: @CommanderguyonYT01 that's a solved problem. Look for `std::function`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 imagine `memcpy` taking a `std::any` :-)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili :P for me `memcpy` is in the same bag as `void*`. I needed it exactly once (admittetly my time with C++ isnt long enough to make a general statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a method pointer with a void* pointer to the object

No, it is not. More generally, you cannot indirect through a pointer to void at all.

Pointer to void must be casted to an pointer to object type that is compatible with the pointer to member function.

> I don't (and can't) have information of that objects' class

If you know that the type of the object is compatible with the pointer to member function, then you should know what that type is. If you don't know the type, then you don't know that it's compatible and thus cannot call the pointer to member function.